# -bash: Welcome: Command not found (happens on iTerm startup)

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, iterm2

I'm getting this error message every time I start up iTerm on my mac and I have no idea why. I looked in my `.bash_profile`, `.bash_prompt.sh`, and `.bashrc*` files, and I couldn't even find a reference to this "Welcome" command that seems to be firing. Lastly, I checked iTerm's preferences directly, and there seems to be nothing in there that would fire off this Welcome command.

Any idea where this could be coming from?

Comment: How about `.profile` ?

Comment: I actually don't have a `.profile` file in my root directory

Comment: `.profile` is ignored anyway if `.bash_profile` is present. Check `/etc/profile` (and anything sourced from there), though.

Comment: Run a script (gash.sh in my example), it can just contain `echo hello world` as `bash -xil gash.sh`.  That should trace the start-up files.

Comment: If you do my suggested trace, you might want to redirect `stderr` to a file so you can search it later:  `bash -xil gash.sh 2> gash.txt`.

Comment: look into /etc/profile
you can try something like this grep -R welcome /etc/*
or try to install the welcome and be free of this error message (brew install welcome])